# Numba nopython mode boolean indexing

Tags: arrays, numpy, boolean-logic, numba, boolean-operations

I'm working with arrays in numba that sometimes return inf or nan as an entry, which I then need to adjust to zero. I'm working in nopython mode, so I want to know if there's a way to use boolean indexing (or multiplication) to adjust any nan or inf elements in the array to zero (array shape is (vertex_number, 1)).

Obviously I can just loop over the array like this:

```
from numpy import isnan, isinf, array, zeros, nan, inf, ones

from numba import jit

v = ones((10, 1))

v[0] = nan
v[-1] = inf
print(v)

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def reciprocal_v(v):
    u = 1 / v
    for i in range(len(u)): # get rid of zero length reciprocals...
        if (isinf(u[i])[0] == True) | (isnan(u[i])[0] == True):
            u[i] = 0.0
    return u
u = reciprocal_v(v)
print(u)
```

I tried boolean multiplication, but inf*0 returns nan, and nan*0 returns nan

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_isnan(x): return isnan(x)

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_isinf(x): return isinf(x)

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def reciprocal_v_bool(v):
    u = 1 / v
    u = u * ~(numba_isnan(u) | numba_isinf(u))
    return u
```

Comment: Is'nt just  : `if (isinf(u[i,0]) | (isnan(u[i,0]))` ?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with numba, but instead it's the result of how numpy handles the multiplication of `nan` and `inf` (and numba follows the convention). If you remove the `jit` decorator, you can see that the un-jitted function returns the same result. This behavior is defined by a standard like the IEEE 754.

I would just stick with the solution you've already come up with that works.

Also as a general note, you don't need functions like:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_isnan(x): return isnan(x)
```

Just `import numpy as np` and then use `np.isnan()` in a numba function. Numba will recognize the numpy function and replace it with the correct form.